# Rhombus rotates in a circle.

Tags: geometry

Two vertexes of the rhombus is on the circle, rotate the rhombus $ABCD$ clockwise around the point A to the rhombus $AB'C'D'$, where the point $B'$ falls on the circle, link $B'D,C'C$.
If $B'D:CC'=4:3$, then value of $tan\angle BAD$ will be?
It seems $B',B,D'$ or $D,D',C'$ are in a straight line on the image, but I can't proof it.By the way, there are also many things that seem right but hard to proof.It confuses me a lot.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution without trigonometry.

---

Link $CB'$ and $DC'$,$$\because DC=AB' \therefore \angle DB'C=\angle ADB'\\$$
Thus, $CB' \parallel AD$ 
Since, $CB \parallel AD$
$C,B,B'$ are in a straight line.
Similarly, $D,D',C'$ are also in a straight line.
Then, draw a line segment $B'H$ perpendicular to DC' which foot is point $H$.
Let the intersection of $CB'$ and $DC'$ be G.
Obviously, $$\triangle DGB'\sim \triangle CGC', $$and
$$\frac{B'G}{CG}=\frac{DB'}{CC'}=\frac{4}{3}$$
Hence $\angle AB'C= \angle DC'B' = \angle B'GC'$
Thus $B'G=B'C$
So $HC=\frac{1}{2}GC'$
Finally,  $tan \angle BAD = tan \angle B'C'D= \frac{B'H}{HC'}=\frac{\sqrt{55}}{3}$
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The congruent sides of the rhombus and its rotation ensure that arcs $\stackrel{\frown}{CD}$, $\stackrel{\frown}{DA}$, $\stackrel{\frown}{AB'}$, $\stackrel{\frown}{B'C'}$ are all congruent, so they subtend congruent inscribed angles (such as $\angle CAD$), which are half the size of target angle $\angle BAD$.

[image]

Since chords $\overline{B'D}$, $\overline{AC}$, and $\overline{AC'}$ each span two of these arcs, they are congruent. Moreover, since inscribed angle $\angle ACC'$ subtends two of these arcs, it is congruent to $\angle BAD$.

Thus, with $M$ the midpoint of $\overline{CC'}$ (and necessarily the foot of the altitude from $A$), we can write
$$\tan\angle BAD = \tan\angle ACC'=\frac{|AM|}{|CM|}=\frac{\sqrt{|AC|^2-|CM|^2}}{|CM|}=\frac{\sqrt{|B'D|^2-\frac14|CC'|^2}}{\frac12|CC'|}$$
If $|B'D|:|CC'|=p:q$, this becomes
$$\tan\angle BAD=\frac{\sqrt{4p^2-q^2}}{q}\quad\stackrel{(p,q)=(4,3)}{=}\quad\frac{\sqrt{55}}{3}$$
which agrees with other solutions given. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

If the angle of rotation is $\phi$ (clockwise) then

$ CC' = 2 \overline{AC} \sin(\dfrac{\phi}{2}) $

and

$ BD' = 2 \overline{AD} \sin(\angle BAC + \dfrac{\phi}{2} ) $

Now, $ \dfrac{\overline{AD}}{\overline{AC}} = \dfrac{1}{2} \sec(\angle BAC) $

Also, from the figure, we have $\phi =  \pi - 4 \angle BAC $

Let $ x = \angle BAC $ , then

$\dfrac{4}{3} = \dfrac{1}{2} \sec(x) \dfrac{ \sin( \dfrac{\pi}{2} -  x ) }{\sin( \dfrac{\pi}{2} - 2 x)}  $

Hence,

$8 \cos(2x) = 3 $

Therefore

$x = \angle BAC = \dfrac{1}{2} \cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{3}{8}\right) $

Thus

$ \angle BAD = 2 x = \cos^{-1} \left( \dfrac{3}{8} \right ) $

Thus $ \cos(\angle BAD) = \dfrac{3}{8} $

From which

$\tan(\angle BAD) = \sqrt{\dfrac{64}{9} - 1} = \dfrac{\sqrt{55}}{3}$

The figure below shows the original rhombus (blue) and its rotated image (red).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $\angle AOD=\angle DOC=\alpha, \angle EOC=\beta, \angle ODC=\gamma$

We have that $\sin \alpha: \sin \beta=4:3$ or $3\sin \alpha=4\sin \beta$, also $\sin(2\alpha+\beta)=0$
Thus,
$$\sin 2\alpha\cos \beta+\cos2 \alpha\sin\beta=0$$
$$2\sin \alpha\cos \alpha \cos \beta+\frac{3}{4}\cos2 \alpha\sin\alpha=0$$
$$2\cos \alpha \cos \beta+\frac{3}{4}\cos2 \alpha=0$$
Using that: $9\sin^2\alpha=16\sin^2\beta \implies \cos \beta=\frac{\sqrt{7+9\cos^2\alpha}}{4}$
$$\cos \alpha \frac{\sqrt{7+9\cos^2\alpha}}{2}+\frac{3}{4}(2\cos^2 \alpha-1)=0$$Thus, we have the equation to find $x=\cos \alpha$: $$x\sqrt{7+9x^2}+3x^2=\frac{3}{2}$$
$$x^2(7+9x^2)=\frac{9}{4}-9x^2+9x^4$$
$$16x^2=\frac{9}{4} \implies x=\frac{3}{8}$$ Next, notice that we need to find $\tan BAD=\tan (\pi-2\gamma)=-\tan 2\gamma$ and $\gamma=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2} \implies \tan BAD=-\tan(\pi-\alpha)=\tan \alpha=\frac{\sqrt{55}}{3}$